# why element div also change its position

Tags: html, css, transition

I am just trying to rotate this element whenever the mouse hovers on it. but it also changes its position. please let me know what's the problem in this code. I am not getting why this happens. Anyone, please help. Any documentation is also accepted.

below is my code.

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    height: 100vh;
}

.spinner{
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition:transform 1s ease-in;

}
.spinner span{

    display: inline-block;

    font-size: 1.7em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-weight: 500;

}
.spinner:hover{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spinner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="spinner.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="spinner">
        <span>Click me</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are losing the main transform property from the .spinner element.

```
.spinner{
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.spinner:hover{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

When you hover, your translation property is replaced with the rotation one. 
**In order to get this to work you need two stack the two transforms in one line, like this:**

```
    .spinner:hover{
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing the values of position and the display property and it will work hopefully.